# Not able to download OBJ file using GetDerivativeManifest

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am trying to download an OBJ file generated from SVF file, using the Autodesk.Forge .NET API method GetDerivativeManifest (C#). The OBJ file has been created successfully. However, the method does not provide a Stream that I can use to retrieve the file and save it locally.

How can I get the OBJ file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a C# sample ready to give you, but I hit the same issue with the Node.js SDK. I worked around by implementing the REST call myself:

```
download (token, urn, derivativeURN, opts = {}) {

  // TODO SDK KO
  //this._APIAuth.accessToken = token
  //
  //return this._derivativesAPI.getDerivativeManifest(
  //  urn,
  //  derivativeURN,
  //  opts)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const url =
      `${DerivativeSvc.SERVICE_BASE_URL}/designdata/` +
      `${encodeURIComponent(urn)}/manifest/` +
      `${encodeURIComponent(derivativeURN)}`

    request({
      url: url,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.access_token
      },
      encoding: null
    }, function(err, response, body) {

      try {

        if (err) {

          return reject(err)
        }

        if (response && [200, 201, 202].indexOf(
            response.statusCode) < 0) {

          return reject(response.statusMessage)
        }

        if (opts.base64) {

          resolve(bufferToBase64(body))

        } else {

          resolve(body)
        }

      } catch(ex) {

        console.log(ex)

        reject(ex)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Here is how I invoke that method within my endpoint:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// GET /download
// Download derivative resource
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
router.get('/download', async (req, res) => {

  try {

    const filename = req.query.filename || 'download'

    const derivativeUrn = req.query.derivativeUrn

    // return base64 encoded for thumbnails
    const base64 = req.query.base64

    const urn = req.query.urn

    const forgeSvc = ServiceManager.getService(
      'ForgeSvc')

    const token = await forgeSvc.get2LeggedToken()

    const derivativesSvc = ServiceManager.getService(
      'DerivativesSvc')

    const response = await derivativesSvc.download(
      token, urn, derivativeUrn, {
        base64: base64
      })

    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')

    res.set('Content-Disposition',
      `attachment filename="${filename}"`)

    res.end(response)

  } catch (ex) {

    res.status(ex.statusCode || 500)
    res.json(ex)
  }
})
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi Philippe,

I came to the same conclusion. By using REST I was able to achieve this successfully. There were actually two problems; one was to retrieve the OBJ from the GetDerivativeManifest (it is a void), and second is that in that method it expects string for the objectIds, while the Autodesk API being called expects integer.

I REST my case :-)

Thank you for helping out, Philippe, appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad you could sort it out. You may want to log an issue against that specific SDK directly on github, so the author knows about it. Also the usual way to thanks on this site is to bump up the rep and mark the answer as solution if it does solves it. Cheers.